# adding element to other elements in a for loop only rendering last item

Tags: javascript, html, scriptlet

I'm hoping to make a tool for myself aka a javascript bookmark that I can use on webpages specifically google forms, i wanted to loop through all questions on a page and add helpful tips or maybe definitions of words if thats what the question was asking. Im having issues appending children to every element, at the moment only the last question is getting anything appended. Heres some of the code im using for this

```
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is an example of some notes");
    x.appendChild(t);                                        
   //getting list of questions
   var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseHeader");

   for(var i = 0;i<questions.length;i++){
       x.innerHTML=i;
       questions[i].appendChild(x);
       console.log(i);
   }
//for some reason only the last question has text visible
```

thank you!

edit: heres the link to the form im using, ive tried other forms aswell but they problem remains the same. The output from the console.log is as follows `code  0 1 2 3 4 //up to the number of questions so i think it may just be a visual bug` https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfuvQKv0KtayB8MwQ-oYj5kf6K8I8dWIzJhqeDqMWZdwMY1mQ/viewform

Comment: Tricky because we don't have your original form. I suggest the following to encourage people to answer.
1. Can you trim out everything that isn't essential to show the problem? For example everything about fonts and styling can be deleted.
2. Can you use Javascript to "console.log" the list of questions, and show us what it looks like?
3. Best of all, can you include a MINIMAL html version of the form (strip out everything that isn't needed) so people here can run your code without Google Forms?

Comment: If x.innerHTML = i, then questions[i] will also be i. Shouldnt x.innerHTML == t?

Comment: Atm i want the questions to get numbered, definitions will come later in the project but for now i just want to be able to number each question